# POST Requests with Ruby Faraday OpenSSL PKCS12

Tags: ruby, post, openssl, pkcs#12, faraday

Good day!

I am trying to send POST requests to a server via ssl connection with .p12 certificate from Windows 7 with Ruby's Faraday library.

Ruby's version is ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]

Faraday gem's version are: faraday (0.14.0, 0.9.2)

1) I have a folder with the following cert files:

- [cert_name].crt,
- [cert_name].csr,
- [cert_name].key,
- [cert_name].p12

2) As to the code, I have the following:

```
require "faraday"
require "json"
require "openssl"
data = [JSON_object]
host = 'https://[domain_name]'
url = '[string]/[string]'
p12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.open('[path_to_folder_with_cert_files]/[cert_name].p12', "rb").read, "[password]")
key = p12.key
cert = p12.certificate
connection = Faraday::Connection.new host, :ssl => {
  :client_cert => cert,
  :client_key => key,
  :ca_file => '[path_to_folder_with_cert_files]/[cert_name].crt',
  :verify => false
}
puts response.status = connection.post do |req|
  req.url(url)
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = @headers["content_type"]
  req.body = data
end
```

Response has 403 Forbidden. I have tested with no ssl connection the data, url, host parameters and the status is 200 OK.

Please help, as I have found no tutorial / question to this particular use of Ruby's Faraday and OpenSSL::PKCS12

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
class Gateway
  def call
    connection.get do |req|
      req.url(url)
      req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml'
      req.body = data
    end
  end

  def connection
    Faraday.new(ssl: ssl) do |builder|
      builder.request :retry
      builder.response(:logger) unless Rails.env.test?
      builder.adapter :net_http
    end
  end

  def ssl
    {
      client_key: client_key,
      client_cert: client_cert,
      ca_file: 'CA.crt' # optional
    }
  end

  def url
    'https://...'
  end

  def client_key
    p12.key
  end

  def client_cert
    p12.certificate
  end

  def p12
    OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(p12_file.read, p12_password)
  end

  def p12_file
   File.open('<path-to-p12-file>', 'rb')
  end

  def p12_password
    'password' # if password protected
  end
end
```

And the usage:

```
puts Gateway.new.call.body
```